# Do you need to ask 5 question that are all positive scored and not deleted/closed on five consecutive days for the Edward hat?

Tags: support, questions, winter-bash

My question is virtually the title...

I am just wondering does all the five question you asked in Winter Bash for trying to get the Edward hat all on 5 consecutive days? Let's say (just an example):

- 12/16 positive scored question not closed/deleted
- 12/17 same as above ^
- 12/18 No question asked...
- 12/19 positive scored question not closed/deleted
- 12/20 same as above ^
- 12/21 same as above as well ^

If I did the above on the above dates, would I get the Edward hat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not get the hat, as the full description of the hat states:

> Each day during a 5-day period, ask a positively scored question and have no negatively scored, closed or deleted questions.

Your 5-day count reset on 12/18 because you did not ask a question on that day. After 12/21, you would have needed to ask 2 more questions to receive the hat.